# Rails - how to get category name out of database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Product which has a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with a category. I am using simple_form with Twitter Bootstrap integration, in order to generate Checkboxes, that allow to select multiple Categories per Product.

Unfortunately when I ask Rails for "product.categories", what I get is :
"[#]"

How can I access the name of this Category?
"product.categories.name" doesnt seem to work.

Comment: you should get array of category object when you write product.categories. then you can follow the answer of Sachin R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an array of names of categories of product by this:

```
product.categories.collect(&:name).to_param
```

Comment: You are right. When i use your snippet I get -> "[&quot;Projects&quot;]" without quotes. Is there a way to get rid of the [&quot; and &quot;] ? I managed to do it using -> product.categories.collect(&:name).to_param but I am not convinced it is the most "elegant" way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get objects of categories

```
product.categories.each do |category|
  category.name
end

or 

product.categories[0].name #for first category from categories
```